# Less accessible - Iconsistent accessibility

Tags: c#

Here my code. I don't understand the mistake.

```
Iconsistent accessibility: property type 'ProjetoClinica.Model.Pais' is less accessible than
property 'ProjetoClinica.Model.Estado.Paises' 
D:\Projeto\Clinica\ProjetoClinica\ProjetoClinica\Model\Estado.cs    39  21  ProjetoClinica
```

`Pais` is a class

```
public class Estado : ICrud
{

    #region Atributos Privados

    private Pais paises;

    #endregion

    #region Atributos Públicos

    public Pais Paises
    {
        get { return this.paises; }
        set { this.paises = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your `Paises` property is publicly visible within a public class, then its type, `Pais`, must be marked `public`. Chances are `Pais` is marked `internal`, `protected`, `protected internal` or `private`.

Code that can call `Paises` must be able to see the type it returns, so you'll have to change `Pais`' access modifier to `public`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that `Paises` is a `public` property on a `public` type, but the type it returns (`Pais`) is not a `public` type, so users of this assembly will not be able to access it. This doesn't make sense, so the compiler complains.

You can either:

- make `Pais` a `public` type, so users of the assembly can access it, or
- make `Estado` an `internal` type, so it is not visible to users of the assembly